# Integration Test for a static method in Java

Tags: java, spring, testing, integration-testing, powermockito

I have the following method and I am trying to test it in my Integration Test:

```
public List<CountryCodeDTO> getAllCountryCodes() {
        List<CountryCodeDTO> countryCodes = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String country : Locale.getISOCountries()) {
            Locale locale = new Locale("", country);
            CountryCodeDTO countryCodeDTO = new CountryCodeDTO();
            countryCodeDTO.setCountryCode(country);
            countryCodeDTO.setName(locale.getDisplayCountry());
            countryCodes.add(countryCodeDTO);
        }
        return countryCodes;
    }
```

As a beginner for Integration Testing, I have really no idea about how I should test it. On the other hand, I have found something e.g. PowerMock, but I think it is for Unit Test rather than Integration Test. So, how should I test this method?

Please note that it seems to be a unit test, testing only this method, but as as result, we also test the other methods e.g. save, find, delete, etc. in Integration Tests. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you would want to test here exactly; `CountryCodeDTO` just seems like a wrapper around Java's `Locale`. Would you want to assert that certain country codes get returned correctly? Also, as you're writing an _integration test_, you'd want to avoid mocking (mostly) and use the actual implementations across the call stack -- in your example you would use the actual implementation of Java's `Locale.getISOCountries()`.

Comment: I would write a unit test for that method which did no mocking, and just checked that the returned list was the correct size and that one of the `CountryCodeDTO` entires contains the expected data. Incidentally, your design could be improved by giving `CountryCodeDTO` a constructor which takes the country and name and them making the class immutable, that is, making the fields final and removing the setters. As for an integration test, there would be no individual integration test for the `getAllCountryCodes` function, it will be exercised as part of other integration tests.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Thanks for reply, but I do not understand what you suggested. So, you see the method and should I test it in an integration test? If so, how can I test it?

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks a lot, I also thought that. So, in this case, as I am writing Integration Test, I should test `getAllCountryCodes` method while I write a Unit Test. Is that true?

Comment: That's what I'd do.